# Error using Rows function with a query that returns nothing

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I need to count how many "Yes" or "N/A" values there are in a particular column on a sheet, so I have a formula like this:

```
=Rows(Query(INDIRECT('SheetName'!A:H"), "SELECT * WHERE (Col3=""Yes"" OR Col3 = ""N/A"")",""))
```

But when the WHERE clause filters out every row I get an error "error: Query completed with an empty output."

When the query's output is empty I'd hope to get a 0 for the "row count".  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way might be to wrap the entire formula in `=IFERROR(...;0)`.

Comment: Thanks... no idea why I didn't get notified of your answer.  As it turns out that's the exact solution I came to a few days later.

Comment: Is there a succinct way to prevent the "#NA" error, and not rescue all other types of errors? You could use `IF` and `ISNA`, but then you would have to copy the entire formula if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is **very** roundabout, especially when there is a built-in function for counting the number of matching cells in a column or row: COUNTIF. Also, if you happened to move your source sheet around, your QUERY may stop giving you the correct result. Try this, assuming column C is the one you're after to count how many occurrences of "N/A" and "Yes" appear.

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,"N/A")+COUNTIF(C:C,"Yes")
```